# Javascript how to change anchor backgroundcolor based on href

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey

I am trying to write a greasemonkey script to highlight particular topics on a forum page. The hrefs contain a topic number and and I want to change the background color of the anchor text if it matches one of these topics.  I have tried the following function and it's not working, and it seems it's not possible to debug greasemoney scripts with the firefox debugger anymore.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
function highlightTopics() {
  var pattern = /topic3048|topic2145|topic2147/;
  var anchors=document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    if (pattern.test(anchors(i).href) {
      anchors(i).style.backgroundColor = 'GreenYellow';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `anchors[i]` instead of `anchors(i)` maybe?

Comment: OK that was a stupid mistake.  Changed that, and it's still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like was still missing a **)** on the if

```
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    var pattern = /topic3048|topic2145|topic2147/;

    for (var j = 0; j < anchors.length; j++) {

        if ( pattern.test( anchors[j].href ) ) {
            anchors[j].style.backgroundColor = 'GreenYellow';
        } 
        //optional
        else {
            console.log(anchors[j].href);
        }

    }
```

You should try check the firebug console, also use an [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), like Sublime Text, WebStorm.